# Jquery Ajax Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hi all;**

```
var v_name = null;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Testpage.aspx",
    data: "name=test",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(mydata) {


    $.data(document.body, 'v_name', mydata);

}
});

v_name = $.data(document.body, 'OutputGrid');

                alert(v_name);
```

first alert undefined before alert work why ?

Comment: if you want to store the result to use it somewhere else, use $.data()

Comment: $.data(document.body, 'v_name', mydata); to store, $.data(document.body, 'v.name'); to access somewhere else

Comment: you can't/shouldn't access the result right after the ajax call since it runs asynchronous. Put the alert into your success handler or add asycn: false to your .ajax call.

Comment: how to make pls edit my code ?

Comment: @oraclee: Whatever you are going to do with `v_name`, you should do it in the `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you have to place the `alert()` in the `success` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Testpage.aspx",
    data: "name=test",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(mydata) {
       alert(mydata);
    }
});
```

AJAX calls are asynchronous, and therefore JavaScript would evaluate `alert(v_name);` before the server responds to the AJAX call, and therefore before the `success` function is called.

Your AJAX applications must be designed in such a way to be driven by the AJAX response. Therefore anything you plan to do with `mydata` should be invoked from the `success` function. As a rule of the thumb, imagine that the server will take very long (such as 1 minute) to respond to the AJAX request. Your program logic should work around this concept of asynchrony.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Testpage.aspx",
    data: "name=test",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(mydata) {

       alert(mydata);

    }
});
```

Comment: i need code:

var v_name = null;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Testpage.aspx",
    data: "name=test",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(mydata) {

    v_name= mydata;

}
});

alert(v_name);

Comment: @oraclee: Why? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @oraclee, I don't (and I dont think I'm alone here) understand you. If you want to show an alert with the value of mydata once the ajax call completes, then thats what you need to do. Your code will not work, because as others have mentioned $.ajax is asynchronous. In your code, alert(v_name) will be called BEFORE the ajax call has completed, and thus v_name is not set when you show the alert box. This is why its null.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, also keep in mind that by default .ajax GET requests are cached, so depending on your browser, it may look like all of your requests are returning the same response.  Workarounds include (but are not limited to): using POST instead of GET, adding a random querystring to your url for each request, or adding 'cache: false' to either your ajax call or to the global ajaxSetup.